# Magento 2 show normal price with special price on minicart

Tags: price, magento-2.1, overrides, mini-cart

I can set **Normal price** along with **Special price** while put custom function in core file

`vendor/magento/module-weee/Block/Item/Price/Renderer.php`

```
public function getUnitItemPriceExclTax()
{
    $priceExclTax = $this->getItem()->getProduct()->getPrice();

    return $priceExclTax;
}
```

And calling this function into core file,
`vendor/magento/module-weee/view/frontend/templates/checkout/cart/item/price/sidebar.phtml`

So getting both price correctly, but i want to override that

`vendor/magento/module-weee/Block/Item/Price/Renderer.php` block on my custom module.

I have created di.xml with below code :

```
<preference for="Magento\Weee\Block\Item\Price\Renderer" type="<namespace\<module_name>\Block\Item\Price\Renderer"/>
```

And just put that `getUnitItemPriceExclTax()` function in that block.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**You dont need to override Renderer.php file in core and you should never do in core.
You can just changes in sidebar.phtml file and set your changes.**

You can get price from below method:

```
$finalPrice = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();
$normalPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
```

After getting above changes you can do it below code in your template file:

```
<?php if ($block->displayPriceWithWeeeDetails()): ?>
        <span class="minicart-tax-total">
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="minicart-price">
    <?php endif; ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatPrice($block->getUnitDisplayPriceExclTax()); ?> 
        </span>

    <?php if($normalPrice != $finalPrice){ ?>
    <span class="minicart-old-price">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatPrice($normalPrice); ?>
    </span>
    <?php }   ?>
```

I have done changes in Magento Version 2.1.1.

Comment: in Magento2.1.8 It is no longer render in sidebar.phtml. I see from vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_sidebar_item_price_renderers.xml, The template is vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/price.html  Now I do not know how to get origin price.