# How can I display normal price and special price in minicart?

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, knockout

In the mini cart default, a special price will show if a product has a special price (calculated price).
I need to show both prices regular price and special price in mini cart.
Please suggest me a solution if anyone has one.

Comment: Please try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148623/magento-2-show-normal-price-with-special-price-on-minicart

Comment: Thanks @Msquare

Comment: @sagarnakrani Did it work for you? What version of magento are you using?

Comment: @Tsita I am using Magento version 2.4.4 and currently, it has been achieved by adding extra information to the cart item data.